# Start YOCTO Intel x86_64 image on QEMU failure

Tags: qemu

I create Yocto image for architecture x86_64 and run on the QEMU virtual machine by the below qemu command:

> qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 1024 -hda "rootfs.img" -cpu q35 -kernel "vmlinuz" -initrd "initrd"  -append "root=/dev/ram0"

[image]

But the booting process was failed. How to indicate the **rootfs.img** to correct path? What is the problem with QEMU, I tested OK with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to select the correct cpu (i7) and use correct virtual device to mount **rootfs.img**.

> qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 1024 -drive file=rootfs.img,format=raw,**if=virtio** -cpu **Nehalem** -initrd "initrd"  -kernel "vmlinuz" -append "root=**/dev/vda**"

[image]

As the result, the image can boot successfully.

(Refer: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup)